# Modificar una columna con dato especifico usando ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

tengo una tabla con unos usuarios esperando aprobación, cree un botón llamado aprobar, al presionarlo te envía a por ejemplo

> http://localhost:58074/Collaborators/Approved/1 <-- ID del usuario

Esta es mi vista.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Approved";
}

<h2>Approved</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Aprobar" class="btn btn-default" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Regresar", "Index", new { ViewBag.id })
    </div>
}
```

Este es mi controlador.

```
// GET: Collaborators/Approved/
        public ActionResult Approved(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Collaborators collaborators = db.Collaborators.Find(id);
            if (collaborators == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.id = 1;
            return View(collaborators);
        }
```

Necesito que al hacer clic en (Aprobar) me cambie solo el valor status de mi base de datos por un valor en especifico en mi caso el numero 2.

Cabe aclarar que el status actual de un usuario NO aprobado es 1 y quiero que al aprobarlo dicho valor 1 cambie a 2 por ejemplo.

Esta es la linea en el modelo `public int status { get; set; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una vez que recuperas el `Id` del colaborador podrás acceder a sus propiedades y modificarlas:

```
var resultado = (from p in db.Collaborators
    where p.id == id
    select p).SingleOrDefault();

resultado.status = 2;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Finalmente quedaría algo como esto:

```
public ActionResult Approved(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var resultado = (from p in db.Collaborators
        where p.id == id
        select p).SingleOrDefault();

    resultado.status = 2;
    db.SaveChanges();

    ViewBag.id = id;
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Collabotarors");
}
```

Este es un caso demostrativo de cómo funcionaría en general, pero como recomendación siempre que realices cualquier transacción, acceso a datos, etc. es bueno usar un `try` `catch` por cualquier excepción que se llegue a generar.

Comment: en vez de resultado.approved = true; puedo poner resultado.approved = 2; ???

Comment: Sí, ya actualicé la respuesta :)

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta, creo que había un par de cosas por corregir :)